# Magento 1.9.2 images not saved

Tags: magento

Since the upgrade to the latest Magento version images are not being saved when uploaded.

They show up in the media/tmp folder but they don't show up in the product folder.

I have checked permissions of the product folder, `.htaccess` in media folder seems to be good.

I tried the database repair from Magento, there were some issues, but not related to this.

Checked the product.js which was suggested in an other topic here, which was correct as well.

In running out of ideas here.

Any suggestions in where to look?

Comment: Have you tried after upgrading to compare between the core php/js files you have and a vanilla Magento has ?

Comment: I compare /js/ and app/core they seem to be ok. I found out that its saving it in /media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/600x600/3123dsaf3erasdasd/5/7 while it should be in /media/catalog/product/5/7 Any clue on what might cause this?

Comment: is there any error in your log files?

Comment: 2015-10-02T11:44:05+00:00 ERR (3): Recoverable Error: Argument 1 passed to Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute_Data::factory() must be an instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Attribute, instance of Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute given, called in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Info.php on line 133 and defined  in /home/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data.php on line 59. I tried the solution here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73693/mage-eav-model-attribute-datafactory-must-be-an-instance-of-mage-eav-model-a error is still here.

Comment: Nvm, fixed that error by setting eav/entity_attribute to NULL.

Comment: There are no other errors anymore, the problem still exists. As soon as i make a change to an exsitisting product wich already has an image and then save it, The image is gone aswell.